# How to get rid of the one-click attachments in the email list?

Tags: gmail

The new Gmail design includes one-click access to attachments in the messages list. I find it bulks up the message list and I don't use it often. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail has a number of different views - by default the attachment icon is displayed but in the other two they are hidden.

To change, click on the cog in the top right, then select "Display Density".

[image]

Both "Comfortable" and "Compact" will hide the attachment icons